# Load RDF model into Jena SDB

Tags: eclipse, jena, rules

I am trying to load my RDF model into JENA SDB. I have done the connection (and I think it should be fine).
I do not know why but it does not work right. I think it is because of the ARQ library which I have imported into my project but I do not know.

Here the code :

```
    String RDF_FILE = "./prova_rules_M_rdf.owl";
    String className = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
    String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prova_rules"; 
    String DB_USER = "root";                         
    String DB_PASSWD = "";                     


        // create store description
        StoreDesc storeDesc = new StoreDesc(LayoutType.LayoutTripleNodesHash,DatabaseType.MySQL);

        // load database driver
        try {
            Class.forName(className);
            System.out.println("JDBC driver load successfully!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // create SDBConnection
        SDBConnection sdbConnection = new SDBConnection(DB_URL,DB_USER,DB_PASSWD);

        // connect to store
        Store store = SDBFactory.connectStore(sdbConnection,storeDesc);

        // connect store to dataset
        Dataset dataset = SDBFactory.connectDataset(store);

        // prepare the model
        Model tmpModel = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        FileManager.get().readModel(tmpModel,RDF_FILE,"OWL");
        System.out.println(tmpModel.size());

        // add the model into the dataset
        dataset.getDefaultModel().add(tmpModel);

        // all done ... hopefully
        store.close();

    }
```

Here the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ARQ.getContext()Lcom/hp/hpl/jena/sparql/util/Context;
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sdb.SDB.initWorker(SDB.java:87)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sdb.SDB.(SDB.java:61)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sdb.store.StoreFactory.(StoreFactory.java:40)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sdb.SDBFactory.connectStore(SDBFactory.java:117)
    at CreateOntModel.main(CreateOntModel.java:94)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NoSuchMethodError` indicates that you have an inconsistent set of jars on the runtime classpath (Eclipse build path). Make sure you have only one copy of each Jena jar on the project build path as well.

Using maven with Eclipse will manage the dependencies automatically.